# Unstable hotspot connection but not during speedtest

Tags: networking

I'm using a **Samsung Galaxy M53 5G** connected in 4g+ with a Vodafone SIM and send the connection through hotspot to a **Lenovo E495**.

They are next to each other and I'm outdoors on board a bus, in an area where the signal gets very good.

I'm experiencing a very slow and unstable hotspot connection. The strange behavior is that when I start a [Ookla speedtest](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli#ubuntu) on the PC, the hotspot connection become much more stable and faster. I have the doubt (probably wrong) that the ISP speeds up my connection when I perform the speedtest...

There is a technical reason for that and how to improve the hotspot connection?

The hotspot is set with these parameters:

- 2.4 GHz (the other option is 5GHz but I have the devices on my knees so I want to prevent too much waves on my body)
- transmission channel: auto
- MAC address type: casual
- security: WPA2-Personal

The WiFi settings on Lenovo are:

- IPV4 method: automatic (DHCP)
- DNS: 8.8.8.8
- routing: automatic
- It says the signal power is excellent

Thanks

Comment: I had one AP which mysteriously would keep disconnecting unless I had a open connection - I kept an IRC client up just for that. I wonder if you get the same behavior on a different speedtest site, and/or you had a constant/low usage connection up

Comment: @JourneymanGeek can you give me additional info please?

Comment: This was like... 20 years ago. I had a dlink AP that would keep disconnecting unless you had an open, long running connection up. IRC used very little data and would keep the connection open. ISP MIGHT be speeding things up on speedtests too, some do but since ookla's the big one, trying a different speed test is an idea too

Comment: The signal strength of Wi-Fi in both 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands is limited to more or less the same level. Do not confuse 5G and 5 GHz.